# ExecutorService created on Stack

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Let's say I have some request objects from a class called `MyRequest`. I want to batch requests together. As a consequence, I have a `Runnable` implementation, which batches those request according to some rules (requests are passed as parameter). Let's call it `MyBatchedRequestHandler` In order to execute multiple batches concurrently I use an `ExecutorService`.

Now, what happens if I create such an `ExecutorService` within a method-body - without an external reference to it - and execute a new `Runnable` instance for my request. Like this:

```
public void execute(Collection<MyRequests> requests){
      Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new MyBatchedRequestHandler(requests));
}
```

*Due to the fact that there is no reference to the `ExecutorService` instances, I assume it might be garbage collected (even if it has not completed the requests yet)... Is my assumption correct?* However, there is still a reference to the request objects... Does that prevent the garbage collector from collecting it?